# Genymotion Virtualbox configuration

Tags: configuration, virtualbox, virtualization, genymotion

I have downloaded Genymotion and installed it with Oracle Virtualbox 5.0.10 on Windows 10/64bit.
I keep getting the errors:

1. Virtualization engine not found.
2. Cannot rename this connection. A connection with the name you specified already exists. Specify a different name.

I've tried uninstall/reinstall, deleted unused network adapters in device manager. I'm at loss.

Thank you all in advance for any help/idea.

Answer (score 0):

You must go the VirtualMachine preferences under File in the menu. Then choose the Network setting, then Host-only Networks.

You can use the - button to delete all of the Ethernet Adapters that you have there.

Then create a new one and use the following settings:

IPv4 Address : 192.168.1.201
IPv4 network mask : 255.255.255.0

Then in the DHCP server tab:
Address: 192.168.1.100
mask: 255.255.255.0
Lower address: 192.168.1.101
Upper address : 192.168.1.199

Check to see which Ethernet adapter # you have now set up - this might be important later on.
Click OK for all the open boxes or save whatever you have.

Then try and run genyMotion again. 
This worked for me.

There is one more thing you may have to do if this still doesnt work.
Go to Network and sharing centre . Change adapter settings and disable all the Ethernet connections EXCEPT for the Ethernet adapter you have just created.

I hope that helps
Daniel

Comment: Thank you Daniel,
That doesn't seem to fix my problem.
Maybe it's something I'm missing?

Comment: @Calin What problems still occur? What error message do you get when starting up GenyMotion? What happens if you open up VirtualBox?  I based my answer on this video maybe it will help to watch it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pd7ZtO-87A

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply.
I have updated the VirtualBox and Genymotion yesterday to the latest version.
I have both VirtualBox and Genymotion open and I have created a device I Genymotion.
when I try to start it from Genymotion I can see it starting in VirtualBoX then powering off and I am getting the VirtualBox cannot start device in Genymotion.

Comment: Per your [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35119400), you're getting this error: "AMD-V is disabled in the BIOS".  You say "I don't have any option to enable/disable the virtualization on BIOS".  It sounds like your CPU/PC hardware simply doesn't support the VT extensions you need: http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/definition/Intel-VT

Comment: Thamk you for your replies.I figured it out that laptop doesn't support virtualization and it's time for a new one.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 
   Almost every GNU/Linux system comes with an installer package for Oracle VM VirtualBox.
Browse for the Oracle VM VirtualBox installer in your directories.

If you do not have the installer or if you need to install a specific version, download and install VirtualBox for Linux hosts from the Download VirtualBox page.
When installing VirtualBox, in the Custom setup window, make sure VirtualBox Networking is enabled.

Go to the Genymotion download page and download the Linux package corresponding to your system.
Run the following commands:

```
chmod +x <Genymotion installer path>/genymotion-<version>_<arch>.bin

cd <Genymotion installer path>

./genymotion-<version>_<arch>.bin -d <Genymotion installer path>
```

Run Genymotion using the following command:

```
cd <Genymotion installer path>

./genymotion
```