# VirtualBox - Virtualbox failed to open a session for the virtual machine

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, virtualization

I am using Genymotion to create a virtual device but it won't start.
I am getting this error:

AMD-V is disabled in the BIOS (or by the host OS) (VERR_SVM_DISABLED).

Result Code: 
E_FAIL (0x80004005)
Component: 
ConsoleWrap
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}

I don't have any option to enable/disable the virtualization on BIOS.
I have tried to disable VT-x/AMD-V from the UI bit it would not unless I switch to Linux 32bit and 1 CPU in which case it won't boot asking for chose the correct setting for the CPU configuration.
I also tried the command line without any success.

I appreciate any help. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you need to get a PC with a CPU that has ["virtualization extensions"](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/processors/000005486.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I am planning in buying a new laptop but I was hopping there was a way to do it on my laptop, there must be others that have the same problem...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFJYpT7L5ag

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pSGo7FHLSNY